# sql server query about unix time

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix-timestamp

i have a 4-column table with ships' signal entries. 1st column is unix time with a 3-month rows entry. 2nd is the name of a ship. 3rd is the longitude. 4th is the latitude. There are many entries of the same ship with different time. i want a sql server query, to find  the table rows which a ship , doesn't have an entry for more than 10 minutes and less than 5 hours.

Comment: So what part are you having problems with and what have you tried so far?

Comment: You are asking us to write a query for you yet you did not even bother to provide a proper DDL.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do things for you (CTE + ROW_NUMBER() and self join):

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT  unixtime, 
        shipname, 
        longitude, 
        latitude, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipname ORDER BY unixtime) as rn
FROM YourTable)

SELECT *
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.shipname = c2.shipname and c1.rn = c2.rn -1
    AND (c2.unixtime - c1.unixtime) between 600 and 18000
WHERE c2.unixtime IS NULL
```

Epoch timestamp (unixtime) is a number of seconds since `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` so you need to convert 10 minutes in seconds (600) and 5 hours in seconds (18000).